# How relink all link after initiallayoutcompleted

Tags: javascript, gojs

I Listen to "INITIAL LAYOUT COMPLETED" event for adding to linktemplate the option avoidsNodes for performance reason. When i set it the routes dosen't be updated and overlap nodes.

```
this._diagram.addDiagramListener('InitialLayoutCompleted', () => {


            this._diagram.linkTemplate =
            $(go.Link,  // defined below
                {
                    routing: go.Link.AvoidsNodes, // go.Link.AvoidsNodes
                },
                new go.Binding('points', 'points').makeTwoWay(),
                $(go.Shape, { stroke: '#fff', strokeWidth: 1 })
            );

            const Pointers: any = this._diagram.model.toJson();
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to modify the existing templates nor do you want to replace them.  The latter causes all of the Links to be re-created again.

Instead, leave the **Link.routing** as not `AvoidsNodes` in the link template.

Then in your "InitialLayoutCompleted" **DiagramEvent** listener, you could do something like:

```
this._diagram.links.each(l => l.routing = go.Link.AvoidsNodes);
```

Better, you could do that only for those Links that needed it.